# Does $(L-\lambda I )=0$ mean that $\lambda$ must be an eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am working on a proof that if $\lambda$ is the root of a linear operator's minimal polynomial, then it must be an eigenvalue of the linear operator.

I reach a point in my proof where I have, $(L-\lambda I) = 0$. Is this sufficient to show it is an eigenvalue? This is what is tripping me up: if $(L-\lambda I)= 0$ then for any nonzero vector, wouldn't it be true that $Lv-\lambda v = 0$ meaning any nonzero vector would be an eigenvector rather than specific vectors?

Comment: Um, I can't be sure, but if $L$ is your linear operator and you've gone from "$\lambda$ is a root of the minimal polynomial of L" to $(L - \lambda I) = 0$, then you're more than likely to have made a mistake somewhere (or else you've got some other additional conditions in place, like say you're only considering a subspace of your total space). You'd have to post more for us to tell, but as stated that looks extremely fishy to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is similar to the characteristic equation, which tells us the eigenvalues of any given operator(matrix). The characteristic equation for a matrix $L$ is $$\det(L-\lambda I)=0$$ if $$(L-\lambda I)=0$$ then all that we have is the zero matrix, which just tells us that $$L=\lambda I$$ i.e., our matrix is just a scaled up identity matrix. It does seem to be true that any vector $\nu$ is and eigenvector of $L$ if $$L=\lambda I$$ but that is just a trivial thing since $$L=\lambda I \Rightarrow L\nu = \lambda I\nu =\lambda \nu$$ So, you are right, but only in the special case. In the more general case, you must compute the values of $\lambda$ satisfying $$\det(L-\lambda I)=0$$

Answer (score 4):

$L - \lambda I = 0$ if and only if $L = \lambda I$ for some $\lambda$ in the desired field. You are correct. If $L$ is as defined above, then any vector would be an eigenvector. I think the criterion you were looking for is that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue if $\det(L - \lambda I) = 0$.

Comment: @Physor Thanks. I'll edit that out.